# Abiword on heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, abiword

I am trying to install abiword on heroku, by wrapping it in a ruby gem.

I statically compiled a 64 bit binary for abiword using the following commands

```
$ ./configure --enable-shared=no --enable-static=yes
$ make
```

I then take the abiword binary from the above compile and place it in my ruby gem directory structure and build it.

I subsequently pushed this gem to github.

Now I try to install it on heroku.

The install works fine.

When I try to run the line of code that calls abiword raises the following error

```
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/abiword-8f24c3c3c8ef/bin/abiword: error while loading shared libraries: libfribidi.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now why is it trying to find a shared library. Should it not have a static copy of this library to work with.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn;t make it work. So I moved all my code to AWS EC2 directly ( bypassing heroku )